# After deploying a webpage, can the user change a source file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I want the user (non-public webpage, so only a few people will have access) to be able to save the field preference that they collectively want to keep when the webpage refreshes.

This currently works locally (localhost:3000), but I want to know if this will still work when the webpage is deployed/up and running

[image: Fields menu, wanting to save preferences]

Here is where I read in the .json file to look at the saved preferences

```
let CONFIG = require('../assets/savedFieldsPreferences.json');
```

This is if they choose to save new preferences, it'll send a request to the backend

```
<button onClick = {()=>{
                client2.send(JSON.stringify(State.values.Fields))
            }}style = {{marginTop: "1rem", height: "30px", fontSize: "16pt", fontWeight: "bold", backgroundColor: "lightblue"}}>Save Preferences (Will Reload Page)</button>
```

The backend writes to the .json file, and then the page will request to reload

```
const server2 = http.createServer();
server2.listen(8001);
const wsServer2 = new webSocketServer({
  httpServer: server2,
  maxReceivedFrameSize: 131072,
  maxReceivedMessageSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024,
  autoAcceptConnections: false
});

wsServer2.on('request', function(request) {
  var userID = 10;
  console.log((new Date()) + ' Recieved a new connection from origin ' + request.origin + '. 2');
  // You can rewrite this part of the code to accept only the requests from allowed origin
  const connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);
  clients[userID] = connection;
  connection.on('message', function(message) {
    //let fields = JSON.parse(message.utf8Data)
    let fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFile('./sql-statistical-analysis/src/assets/savedFieldsPreferences.json', message.utf8Data, 'utf8', function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    //console.log('complete');
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: Wait, so what's your question?

Comment: Will the functionality of modifying the .json src file still work after the webpage is deployed? For anyone accessing the webapp on their own device

Comment: Because you're requiring the JSON file at the server start, changes to the original file won't reflect your current object in memory unless you re-require it. Whenever you mutate your option object, re-save it to disk as you're doing, then _also_ update your current object in memory reflecting the options. That way your data persists even when your server is down, and when you restart the server you'll still have the options.

Comment: Have you considered saving flags to localStorage? Downside is that it'll be device-specific and won't sync across all of a user's devices, but it may simplify your implementation. Just use a boolean flag for each desired field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploying isn't anything special. It will be running on computer, just like yours, nothing special.

You can actually test how it will behave with multiple users by opening multiple tabs of your programs or locally opening your program on different device. Device will have to be on the same network as your computer on which web server is running.

On your computer that is running he server open Command prompt and type `ipconfig`. You will see your local IPv4 address. Now take your phone, make sure it's connected to same network (WiFi, not mobile data) and in browser type in your IPv4 address of PC followed by port, so something like `192.168.0.98:3000`. It should open your web page on your phone.

Problem that you will run into is that you store your preferences on your server. Meaning that they will be shared between everyone, 1 file for all the users. Meaning that if somebody will change them after refreshing the page it will be changed for everyone, since preferences are just whatever is saved in that 1 file on server.

If you want user specific preferences just use localStorage.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: While testing this out with the methods you mentioned, I now run into an error of the websocket not connecting to ws://127.0.0.1:8001 on the other devices that are on the same network. I edited the websocket section in the original post, hope this helps

Comment: @AnthonyTheNguyen that's because you have to manually expose the server to your network, otherwise it'll be local on your machine (I don't think you should be doing this though; the question wasn't clear when this answer was posted, and it doesn't directly answer your issue).

Comment: Thank you @code, the answer given and the comments you have provided are helping me greatly to understand more about webservers. Both points have helped answer my question in a way. Though now I have another issue with the websocket and server to handle.

Comment: Make sure you are connecting to right machine. In websocket adress ip needs to be the same as for webserver, because they run on the same machine. So if your PC ipv4 is 192.168.0.98 for example you need to connect to 192.168.0.98:3000 and webscoket needs to be ws://192.168.0.98:8001

Comment: Ip 127.0.0.1 is a special reserved IP that means same thing as localhost. So when you try to connect from your phone to ws://127.0.0.1:8001 it tries to connect to itself so your phone at port 8001, but you websocket is running on your PC

Comment: @AssGoblin69 Changing the webserver and the websocket ip to the same address, the server's ip, allowed me to access and use the websocket as needed across all devices on the same network, along with the answer you have provided to start. Thank you!

Comment: Happy I could help. Next step for you would be to make your application available to whole internet, not only your local network (basically deploying). This is actually easier then you think, your target ip becomes your public ip, so ip of your router. Routers IP is public because it is exposed to the whole world and anyone can attempt to connect to it (local network is a tiny network in itself that connects to web thru router and it's public ip). So connection goes to router and router needs to know where to send it, since there is multiple devices connected to it. You need to tell it where.

Comment: Your steps would be something like go to google type "whats my ip" to get your public ip. Replace it to file. Go ot router settings, something like 192.168.0.1 in your browser url bar, look at the bottom of your router. Find port forwarding and set it up from port 3000 to (your PC local ip):3000 so it's redirected to your PC, same for websocket 8001 (doesnt need to match, e.g redirect port 80 (default) to 3000). Now theoretically it should work (might have open ports in your PC firewall, although should be automatic). That's it your app is 'deployed'. Also beware your PC ports are exposed